# How to work out paths on a localhost

Tags: joomla, path

I transferred an online Joomla site to a localhost and I'm having trouble finding the correct paths for some audio and image files. Online, the paths are  `'/templates/beez_20/audio/word_set1/' and '/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/'`. But I can't, for the life of me, work out the correct localhost paths.

The file structure is similar for online and localhost sites. On the local harddrive the pathways are  `'/var/www/e2tw/templates/beez_20/audio/word_set1/'` and `'/var/www/e2tw/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/'.`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For server side actions (like uploading and deleting) you can use:

```
JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/beez_20/audio/word_set1/';
JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/';
```

And if you want to add images to sites, etc. you can use

```
JUri::root() . 'templates/beez_20/audio/word_set1/';
JUri::root() . 'templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/';
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand where the above code goes. The paths I quoted came from the page html files.

Comment: well page html files are rendered in Joomla, so they must be in the template's index.php file or in extension you're using. Check template index.php files and i'm pretty sure you will find paths there, so you just need to replace them.

Comment: some of the pages on the site reference up to 50 audio files specified within the page html and accessed by jquery onclick events, and several image files (it's a language learning site). Even if the path were specified in the index.php, there would still have to be a reference to it in the html, presumably with php code (of which I am nearly totally ignorant) :(

Comment: I've tried this: src="<?php echo JURI::root();?>templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/lamp_non-hover_20.png"  but it doesn't work either. Any help/comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: First of all you need to figure out where those links are listed. Then we will find a solution :)

Comment: When you say 'links' I presume you're referring to the paths, right? I've looked thru the template (beez_20) index.php and there's not (as far as I can see!) any place where the paths or JPATH_ROOT or JUri::root() are listed.

Comment: Why is it that the paths I'm using for the online joomla site are understandable in terms of standard path notation in html, while achieving the same effect on the localhost site seems to be dependent on php code?